# Unwrapping an Optional value with UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have two codes in `switch method`

```
case 1:
   let loginVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"LoginVCID") as! LoginViewController
   mainNVC.viewControllers = [loginVC]

            break
case 2:
    let mainVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"MainVCID") as! MainViewController
    mainNVC.viewControllers = [mainVC]

            break
```

When my code runs on the ***case1***, it works well.
But, when it runs on the ***case2***, it crashed with this error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

What is happened?

Comment: I would cross check the identifier name

Comment: I guess the class of the second view controller is not set to the custom class. And be aware that you don't need `break` in Swift.

Comment: Check "MainVCID" storyboard identifier existing or not and also make sure that class is MainViewController or not

Answer (score 0):

**First**: Check if identifier "MainVCID" is spelled correctly in your Storyboard's Identity Inspector (Second Section: Identity, Storyboard ID)

**Second**: Check if the MainVCID's Class is the Class MainViewController the section Custom Class above

Since the first one is working fine I guess you did just a little muddleheadedness mistake :)

Comment: guard let mainVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"MainVCID") as? MainViewController else {
                return false
            }

Comment: I checked it by this code. but, it still crashed :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `break` commands, you don't need them in Swift.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry.